# Multiple Lines in a single cell separated by a comma using Excel Macros

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Hi there I have an excel cell with multiple items in it. They are all separated by a comma. When the excel workbook is generated it will automatically generate the items and split each item by a comma. The problem however is when I want to run an excel macro I want the each item to be on a separate line. Essentially line break after each comma. The problem with this is I'm not sure how many time there will be in the cell at a time so it needs to be dynamic. Any ideas?

Update:

```
Dim originalApplications As String
Dim splitApplications As Variant
Dim i As Integer

originalApplications = Range("E2").Value


splitApplications = Split(originalApplications, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(splitApplications)

    MsgBox splitApplications(i)

Next i
```

Now I just need to figure out how to line break it.

Comment: Yeah I know the split function its just actually merging it into one cell.

Comment: like `Range("E2").Value = Replace(Range("E2").Value, ",", "," & vbnewline)`???

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you need to assign each value to a cell

```
const startRow = 10
const assignCol = 1
For i = 0 To UBound(splitApplications)

    Cells(i+startRow,assignCol).Value = splitApplications(i)

Next i
```